# Stripe payment & User registration

Tags: php, wordpress, payment

I have a website which consists of FrontEnd part (wordpress) and a backend for users, which is custom (php).

I'd like to add stripe payment, but want users to pay first, and then enter personal details & register an account.

So, here is what I'm planning to do:

- Get Stripe plugin for wordpress (https://wordpress.org/plugins/stripe-payments/   or   https://wpsimplepay.com/), as it is easy to work with and works well. 
  But , plugin doesn't create a user after successful transaction, it just opens a page with transaction details. 
  Even If it would create a user, my backend use different db with special user fields, so, I'd like to create a script which would add new user after successful payment.

The question is the following:
After successful payment, does the generated page with transaction details has POST variables with user email, name... payment id. etc?

Or, It's much easier to integrate hardcoded stripe payment api into custom payment page?

Thanks

Comment: Once the customer reaches the Stripe stage you've lost their identity so you need to have them login first. Incentivise this by offering special deals or bonuses for signing up, and that they can save their cart for later when they get a login to your cart.

Comment: I decided to add a registration form on - "successful transaction" page. So, after they paid they enter all account details and get registered.

Comment: Cool glad you resolved it.